# Why do we define Symplectic groups with Transpose and not hermitian adjoint?

Tags: group-theory, transpose, symplectic-linear-algebra, hermitian-matrices

In the definition of a symplectic group over a field, we take the definition: all matrices $S$ of some dimension $2n$, such that $$S^T \Omega S = \Omega$$ where omega is a skew-symmetric matrix (bi-linear form).

When this is over complex fields we do not swap the transpose to conjugation, we keep the transpose. Is there an analagous hermitian group, in analogy with Unitary and Orthogonal matrices?

In essence my question is if the matrices $S$ such that $$S^\dagger\Omega S = \Omega$$ form a group as well, and if so what group?

Comment: Have you tried to show that the set of such matrices is a subgroup of invertible matrices? Is it stable by product, etc?

Comment: (You might need to also think about what condition on $\Omega$ should replace "skew-symmetric".)

Comment: If you introduce conjugation then it's natural to ask $\Omega$ to be skew-hermitian. But then preserving $\Omega$ is equivalent to preserving $i\Omega$, which is hermitian, so you just have a unitary group.

Comment: You might get something out of these notes of Cameron: http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~pjc/class_gps/

Comment: Thank you all so much! It's clear now